# How to use absolute path for templateUrl and styleUrls? - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application which contains multiple `components`. Recently one of the requirements of the application changed, which meant I had to convert all existing **relative** Urls to **absolute**.

So far everything went smoothly as planned, until I came across the `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` in the `components`. One example of the components is shown below with it's absolute path. Unfortunately when I try to input the absolute path instead of the relative for both these properties it gives me an error (also attached). I tried looking onto various `issues` on github as well as a few examples on **stackoverflow** and **stackexchange**, but I can't get them to work for me

**src/app/views/login/login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OauthService } from 'src/app/services/oauth/oauth.service';
import { LoggerService } from 'src/app/services/logger/logger.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
/*
methods and properties etc etc
.
.
.
*/
```

Here is the **heirarchy** of my application for reference:

[image]

The **tsconfig.json** for this application (contains the `baseUrl`):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The error I receive when I try to run the application on my browser while using `absolute` path for these two properties:

[image]

Comment: Sometime angular CLI failed to detect proper changes. Please re run `ng serve` once more.

Comment: @RANJITPATRA Nope, I've run `ng serve` three times, error remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a year old question, but I just manage to make it work with just '/'.

e.g.: `templateUrl: '/src/app/common/templates/enquiry-page/enquiry-page.html',`

I'm running on Angular 8.